# Terraform Error: "role" ({aws_iam_role.myrole.arn}) is an invalid ARN: arn: invalid prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-lambda, terraform, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use existing aws_iam_role for already created resource with terraform_remote_state and Workspaces. When I apply for first time terraform apply all the resources are created successfully, when I switch to other Workspace I see ARN error.

The error when I run Terraform plan is:

```
     Error: "role" ({aws_iam_role.mypayload.arn}) is an invalid ARN: arn: invalid prefix
    │
    │   with aws_lambda_function.mylambda,
    │   on main.tf line 64, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda":
    │   64:   role          = "${data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.mypayload}"
    │
    ╵
```

My main configuration looks like that:

main.tf

```
    data "terraform_remote_state" "remote_state" {
      backend   = "s3"
      workspace = "dev"
      config = {
        bucket = "my/bucket/"
        key    = "dev/global/s3/terraform.tfstate"
        region = "us-west-2"
      }
    }

resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda" {

  function_name = var.function_name
  filename      = data.archive_file.mypayload_zip.output_path
  description   = var.description
//  role          = aws_iam_role.mypayload.arn
  role          = "${data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.mypayload}"
  handler       = var.lambda_handler
  runtime       = var.compatible_runtimes
  timeout       = 90

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.mypayload_zip.output_base64sha256
  publish          = true

}
```

In my IAM configuration I have:

iam.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "mypayload" {

  name = var.iam_role_name

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

output "mypayload" {
  value = aws_iam_role.mypayload.arn
}
```

How to resolve this problem?

Regards,

Ivo

Comment: Why not just use a datasource to get the role by name, instead of trying to pull in the remote state? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_role

Comment: Even if I use the datasource 

data "aws_iam_role" "mypayload" {
 name = aws_iam_role.payload.name } 

for mylambda resource like:  

role = data.aws_iam_role.payload.name

the error is the same. I want to use  terraform_remote_state because I can combine it with S3 backend and pass default workspace for all environments. My idea is to use the same resources for multiple environments.

Comment: Have you tried removing the string interpolation and referencing the value directly, like you do your other values? `role          = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.mypayload`

Comment: Sure, Mark, I did it but unfortunately the error is the same: 

 Error: "role" ({aws_iam_role.mypayload.arn}) is an invalid ARN: arn: invalid prefix
│
│   with aws_lambda_function.mypayload,
│   on main.tf line 68, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "mypayload":
│   68:   role          = data.terraform_remote_state.remote_state.outputs.mypayload

Before to open this question I did research for the common reasons for this error.

Comment: The error message is saying that the actual string "{aws_iam_role.mypayload.arn}" is being passed in as an ARN. That is a string missing a `$` to make the string interpolation work. You are mixing direct resource references with string interpolation, and getting the string interpolation wrong by leaving out a `$` somewhere. It looks like that `$` is missing in the `output` declaration of your other Terraform code that you haven't shown in the question. There is no way this error would be the same if you were using the data source like I mentioned in my initial suggestion.

Comment: I can’t find why the data recourse is giving the incorrect output, I  removed all the  other outputs and checked where I’m using variables but they are not using interpolation except for the payload name. This is strange and I don’t see anything related to the aws_iam_role anywhere.